# How to get text data from help pages in R?

Tags: r, text, extract

Globally, I'm interested in getting all text data from R documentations to put them in data frames and apply text mining techniques.

1. PACKAGE LEVEL: Suppose I'm interested in a package, for instance "utils" and I want to get all text data in a vector.
   This works:

`package_d <- packageDescription("utils")
package_d$Description`

But not this : 
`package_d$Details`

2. FUNCTIONS LEVEL : Same problem but for the functions. I tried this without success:

   `function_d <- ?utils::adist
   function_d$Description`
3. SUB-LEVELS : I would like to extract all the details, descriptions of arguments and values of the functions of a particular package...

Thank you very much for your help !

Comment: Can you be clear exactly what text you are trying to extract with `package_d$Details`? There isn't a Details section in a DESCRIPTION file in a package.

Comment: When I tried this : `> ?utils` in RStudio, there is a section 'Details' precising for the package `utils` : ''This package contains a collection of utility functions."

Comment: OK, that information is not in the packageDescription because it's not in the DESCRIPTION file. That information is in the help page body only.

Answer (score 3):

I couldn't find a built in one, but looking at the source for the functions that do most of the work, here's a function that can extract the text from the help page.

```
help_text <- function(...) {
  file <- help(...)
  path <- dirname(file)
  dirpath <- dirname(path)
  pkgname <- basename(dirpath)
  RdDB <- file.path(path, pkgname)
  rd <- tools:::fetchRdDB(RdDB, basename(file))
  capture.output(tools::Rd2txt(rd, out="", options=list(underline_titles=FALSE)))
}
```

You can use it with the package help pages and function help pages.

```
h1 <- help_text(utils)
h2 <- help_text(adist)
```

You'll get an array of rows from the help page. You can print them with

```
cat(h1, sep="\n")
```

Comment: This was *just* what I needed an hour ago. MrFlick, you should submit this function (or its functionality) to R core ... I cannot imagine why it's necessary to have to try this hard to get at the help text.