# Scrape help content in R

Tags: r, screen-scraping

Is it possible to scrape content of help and print it inside the console?

E.g. i want to find help for barplot find one sentence and then print it to the console.

I can not find any information about it online thus i am counting for your help.

I know it is a general question. If i can improve it do not hesitate to inform me.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51330090/how-to-get-text-data-from-help-pages-in-r You don't seen to web scrape the help files in R. R has plenty of other functions to access the data in help files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can show you an example. You can use [rdocumentation](http://www.rdocumentation.org) to find the `?help` page you need, then use `rvest` in order to scrape its content.

As an example, imagine we'd like to scrape this [page](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/graphics/versions/3.5.1/topics/barplot) and get the phrase "*Creates a bar plot with vertical or horizontal bars*".

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)

url <- "https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/graphics/versions/3.5.1/topics/barplot"
webpage <- read_html(url)

webpage %>% 
  html_nodes("div.container") %>% # <div class="container">
  html_node("section") %>%  # <section>
  "[["(2) %>% 
  html_nodes("p") %>% 
  "["(2) %>% 
  html_text() %>% 
  str_trim() %>% 
  unlist()
  # gives:
  [1] "Creates a bar plot with vertical or horizontal bars."
```

It's important to use the `html_nodes` function and you need to understand a bit about `html`.

If you inspect the page in your browser (right click/inspect), you'll access its `html` code. Then you'll be able to find what you need to scrape by looking at `tags`.

In my example the tags are `div class="container"`, `section`, and the second `p`.

Here a [guide to rvest](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/r-web-scraping-rvest).

Comment: Instead of downvoting please tell me what can be improved in my answer. Downvoting like this doesn't help at all.