# How to include the description of a data set in RMarkdown?

Tags: r, database, r-markdown

I am creating an RMarkdown for teaching and I would like to include the description of the data set on the R Markdown file. For example, if I use the data `marketing` from the R package `datarium`, I would like to be able to include the description obtained with `?marketing` without having to open it online or in R.

```
marketing {datarium}    R Documentation
Marketing Data Set
Description
A data frame containing the impact of three advertising medias (youtube, facebook and newspaper) on sales. Data are the advertising budget in thousands of dollars along with the sales. The advertising experiment has been repeated 200 times.

Usage
data("marketing")
Format
A data frame with 200 rows and 4 columns.

Examples
data(marketing)
res.lm <- lm(sales ~ youtube*facebook, data = marketing)
summary(res.lm)
```

Is this possible?

Comment: This might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51330090/how-to-get-text-data-from-help-pages-in-r

Comment: @MrFlick It is helpful indeed. I can take it as an answer or delete my question. The choice is yours.

Comment: I'm not super great at markdown so if you can post an answer showing how to use that in a code chunk to get the output you want, that would be cool.

Comment: @MrFlick Done... Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using @MrFlick (more like MrShy) suggestion:

[How to get text data from help pages in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51330090/how-to-get-text-data-from-help-pages-in-r)

We can create an R Markdown (I also wanted to hide the function used to get the help text) showing the description of the data as follows:

````
---
title: "Marketing"
author: 'Jon Doe'
date: ""
output: html_document
---

```{r}
library(datarium)

data("marketing")
```

```{r include=FALSE}
help_text <- function(...) {
  file <- help(...)
  path <- dirname(file)
  dirpath <- dirname(path)
  pkgname <- basename(dirpath)
  RdDB <- file.path(path, pkgname)
  rd <- tools:::fetchRdDB(RdDB, basename(file))
  capture.output(tools::Rd2txt(rd, out="", options=list(underline_titles=FALSE)))
}
```
```{r}
# ?marketing
cat(help_extract(marketing), sep="\n")


# Data
head(marketing, 4)
```
````